# How to use regexp to search a list for a string using proc?

Tags: regex, tcl, proc

Trying to dive into TcL Scripting.  I've found that I'm writing a lot of duplicate code & I'd like to figure out how to make it a process, to shorten my scripts.  I may be wrong about the entire idea of the process.  I'm currently copying the foreach loop & changing the names of the variables.  Can I do this with a process so I only type the foreach loop once?

One example, is that I need a process to search a list for strings that "should" be there.  If they're not there, I'd like to output to a report file.

I apologize if this is unclear:

Something like this
        set mandatoryGlobal "{
        ^service tcp-keepalives-in} {
        ^service tcp-keepalives-out} {
        ^service timestamps debug datetime msec}"

```
    set run "{
    version 12.4} 
    {service timestamps debug datetime msec} 
    {service timestamps log datetime msec}
    "

    proc mandatory {mandatoryList config} {
        foreach command $mandatoryList {
            set x 1
            foreach line $config {
                if {![regexp $command $line]} {
                    incr x
                }
            }
            if {$x>[llength $config]} {
                append report $command\n
                return $command\n
            }
        }
    }

    mandatory $mandatoryGlobal $run

    puts $report
    #I would expect that report shows 
    #^service tcp-keepalives-in
    #^service tcp-keepalives-out

    #But I only have this????
    #^service tcp-keepalives-in

    #If I run the foreach loop without the proc & change the variables, 
    #it works as expected
```

Also, I've edited this to try to be more clear about what I'm trying to do.  Donal Fellows answered perfectly after I re-read my question, but I wasn't clear in my goal.  Donal, I really appreciate your effort & an amazing explanation.

Comment: You don't need the `set y`, you can just do `mandatory $value $run`.  But you'll have to explain a little better what your other issues are if Donal hasn't answered them.

Comment: Looks like `lsearch` would have to be used then. Something like `foreach value $mandatoryValues { if {[lsearch -regexp $list $value] == -1} {...} }`

Comment: `string map {process procedure} $question`

Comment: What I'm looking for is something similar to what Jerry is wrote, but I'd like to be able to change the variables so I don't re-write the loops.  I'm really just getting start in programming, so please forgive me if I'm unclear of my goal.  Here's an example of what I did, but I'm re-writing the same code different sections of the list.   append report "Mandatory Commands Not found in Config\n"
foreach command $mandatoryGlobal {
 set x 1
 foreach line $run {
  if {![regexp $command $line]} {
   incr x
  }
 }
 if {$x>[llength $run]} {
  append report $command\n
 }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you've got a list of words and a string to look in them for. Let's assume the words are all well-behaved (no RE-metacharacters) so we can search simply, and that the string just contains simple words too.

Well, in that case we can use `foreach` to go over the list of words, and `lsearch` instead of `regexp` to see if the word is present:

```
proc mandatory {string list} {
    set report {}
    foreach word $list {
        if {[lsearch -exact $string $word] < 0} {
            lappend report $word
        }
    }
    return $report
}
```

Now we need to call this and deal with the results:

```
set run "this is a test list to check for a string"
set value "string that's not in the list"
set unfound [mandatory $value $run]
if {[llength $unfound] > 0} {
    puts "The following words were not in the string: $unfound"
} else {
    puts "All words present and correct"
}
```

Note that we're returning the list of unfound words as a value, storing that in a local variable, and then generating the message after that. (The `llength` check is a good way to see if a list is empty.)

---

We can shorten the `mandatory` procedure using the `ni` (**N**ot **I**n) operator:

```
proc mandatory {string list} {
    set report {}
    foreach word $list {
        if {$word ni $string} {
            lappend report $word
        }
    }
    return $report
}
```

But we ought to be more careful about what words are present. This is where we use regexps; for parsing:

```
proc mandatory {string list} {
    set report {}
    set stringWords [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $string]
    foreach word $list {
        if {$word ni $stringWords} {
            lappend report $word
        }
    }
    return $report
}
```

In some cases, it can be better to build a hash table of the words that are present so that we don't do linear scans of the string's words over and over. Tcl arrays are really hash tables.

```
proc mandatory {string list} {
    set report {}
    foreach word [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $string] {
        set present($word) "some dummy value"
    }
    foreach word $list {
        if {![info exists present($word)]} {
            lappend report $word
        }
    }
    return $report
}
```

(Don't worry about this getting a bit long; it's all bytecode-compiled except for the RE splitter, which frankly doesn't need to be.)

You could write things to use regexps to do the actual searching (`lsearch -regexp` is the key you're looking for), but I wouldn't advise that unless you really need it: for this sort of “check all these things are present”, they're the wrong tool.

Comment: Donal, I've returned to your answer and realized that I had an error in my logic.  You answered my intentions 100%.  I'm using TcL version 8.3, so I don't have some of the handy commands that you used like "ni".  I went ahead with your first example.  I am using lsearch -regexp, because I have to be able to tell the difference between things like {ip http server} & {no ip http server}.  I really appreciate your explanation.